# Why buttons (and also images) tend to dive under the text line?

Tags: html, css, button, vertical-alignment

I want to make a simple search form within a table cell:

```
 <td style="vertical-align: center">
   <div id="search">
       <form action="search" method="get">
         Search:
         <input type="text" value="enter something" class="autoempty" />
         <button type="submit"></button>
       </form>
   </div>
 </td>
```

The button is supposed to have a search icon, using this CSS:

```
div#search button {
  /*reset the normal button behavior*/
  padding: 0px;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-style: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  /*Make it square*/
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  /*set background*/
  background-image: url("../images/search_grey.png");
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  /*fancy cursor*/
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

This is what it looks like:
[image]

The colors show the element dimensions displayed by Firebug. Light-blue is the `<td>` element.
I hoped `vertical-align` property would fix it, but it didn't. I also had the same problems with adding `<img>` tags to text.

Comment: Because the height of the image exceeds the height of the search field - therefore causing it to expand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your CSS

```
#search button, #serach input
{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/xt9H2/)

Comment: It really works... I thought `vertical-align` is only allowed for `TD` elements. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When I have similar alignment problems, especially when dealing with inline-block elements (not experienced enough to know how closely tables relate to that in terms of similarities), what usually helps me is some combination of:

- vertical-align: top;
- adjusting height:;
- adjusting padding-top:; or more commonly, margin-top:; to re-align images from there

AKA: Instead of v-aligning center, v-align from top and use padding/margin to position from there. Hope this helps some.

Comment: and what if the size changes? you would have to recalculate the padding every time you change the image, or the `input` height.